# VB application can execute google analytics script in php page

Tags: vb.net

I need to execute Google Analytics code from my application.
When a user start the application, the application executes the analytics code in one of my php site pages.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create an html page with the Analytics code and add it to your resources.  then add a WebBrowser component to your form and hide it (resize it to 1x1) somewhere.  then add this code to your Form1_Load

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank")
WebBrowser1.Document.Write(String.Empty)
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = My.Resources.YourHtmlPageHere
```